# MySQL query that generates Months as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I am trying to generate a report in MySQL of monthly revenues per source(provider) and what i want is to see the months as columns and the revenues as rows.

I have written this query but i don\t know what to write to get the months as columns:

```
SELECT  T1.provider_id, T2.ad_provider, MONTH(date) AS MONTH, round(SUM(T1.revenue),2) as RevenueTotal 
FROM revenue_metrics as T1
LEFT JOIN ad_provider as T2 ON T1.provider_id=T2.id
GROUP BY T1.provider_id, MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH, `RevenueTotal`  DESC
```

Comment: Update you question and shoe a sample of desired result

Comment: unfortunately i cannot do that, tried to copy a table in the comment but it will publish it as simple text with columns and rows names one after another.

Comment: "Months as columns" you mean 12 columns for each row?

Comment: just all the months i have in the database, it's probably 4-5 months, i dont know. i have 500 k entries.

Comment: Also could you please put sample output of you query mentioned in question.

Comment: you have to fix number of columns, you can't make it dynamic. I am not saying its impossible but require very complex and not good design

Comment: i would love to be able to, but it's companye sensitive data (revenues) :(

Comment: @MihaelaCostea, just replace the data with mock data. Also it is not necessary to have the 500k entries. 20 or so will do.

Comment: yes, i can put a fix number of months, that's not an issue, i just dont know how to write the query for that

Comment: you can change value and paste. :D

Comment: no worries.. you have an answer now by trincot. Which will work to your requirement. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with `CASE ... WHEN`:

```
SELECT    T1.provider_id, 
          T2.ad_provider, 
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  1 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS January,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  2 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS February,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  3 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS March,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  4 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS April,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  5 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS May,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  6 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS June,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  7 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS July,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  8 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS August,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN  9 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS September,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN 10 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS October,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN 11 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS November,
          round(SUM(CASE MONTH(date) WHEN 12 THEN T1.revenue END), 2) AS December
FROM      revenue_metrics as T1
LEFT JOIN ad_provider as T2 ON T1.provider_id=T2.id
GROUP BY  T1.provider_id
```

Note however, that now it no longer makes sense to sort by monthly revenue, since the competing revenues are in different columns now.

Comment: OMG that is awesome :D it's working :D Thank you so much, im just in my 3rd day of working with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

if You Need Month in Numeric Formate Then

```
SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03');
2
```

if You Need Month in String Formate then

```
SELECT MONTHNAME('2008-02-03');
'February'
```